# How do I find all the constructors in a java code base?

Tags: java, linux, bash

I'd like to find all the constructors for a given directory structure with many java files.
I was thinking about a bash shell that greps for the file name in the file to find the constructor.

My goal is to find a classed with many public constructor so that I can refactor them to creation methods.

Thanks!

Comment: Well a bash grep script sounds good. Match the name of the file to lines in the file but I think some IDEs can do this for you

Comment: @DaMainBoss One file can have many non public classes. This may fail.

Comment: @Grzegorz yeah I figured and added the fact that some IDEs might be able to help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're refactoring, I would suggest [you load up Intellij](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) or a similar IDE. It's going to be *much* more reliable at parsing your codebase. Note that there isn't a one-to-one relationship between classes and files (private classes, inner classes etc.)

Intellij's community edition is free, and is very good at finding code usage and performing subsequent refactorings.

Note also that if you're performing refactoring, you should have a set of unit tests to capture regressions due to incorrect refactorings.